# is there a simple way to get group names of a user in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I tried following Code with the help of the **django.contrib.auth.User** and **django.contrib.auth.Group**

```
for g in request.user.groups:
    l.append(g.name)
```

But that failed and I received following **Error**:

```
TypeError at /
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\p4\projects\...\users.py in permission, line 55
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can get the groups of a user with `request.user.groups.all()`, which will return a `QuerySet`. And then you can turn that object into a list if you want.

```py
for g in request.user.groups.all():
    l.append(g.name)
```

or with recent Django

```py
l = request.user.groups.values_list('name',flat = True) # QuerySet Object
l_as_list = list(l)                                     # QuerySet to `list`
```

Comment: In the second case, a QuerySet is printed on print(). The first snippet will return the expected flat list. (django 2.1.7)

Comment: Preferred second version works perfectly fine for me on Django 2.0.13.  
Here it is even better as a one liner: `l = list(request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat = True))`

Answer (score 40):

This is better

```
if user.groups.filter(name='groupname').exists():
    # Action if existing

else:
    # Action if not existing
```

Comment: the fact that is shortest was is absurd

Answer (score 13):

```
user.groups.all()[0].name == "groupname"
```

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: True, not relevant to the current question, but it has helped others to get the group with specific name.

Answer (score 12):

This is probably tad bit too late (I just joined stackoverflow), but for anyone googling for this in early 2018, you can use the fact that django Groups object (by default) comes with the following fields (not exhaustive , just the important ones):

> id, name, permissions, user (can have many users; ManyToMany)

Note that a group can consist of many users, and a user can be a member of many groups. So you can simply filter the **django Groups model** for the current user-session (make sure you have added the relevant groups and assigned the user to his/her group/s):

```
'''
This assumes you have set up django auth properly to manage user logins
'''
# import Group models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

# filter the Group model for current logged in user instance
query_set = Group.objects.filter(user = request.user)

# print to console for debug/checking
for g in query_set:
    # this should print all group names for the user
    print(g.name) # or id or whatever Group field that you want to display
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this option
In you views

```html
  users =User.objects.all().exclude(is_superuser=True)
    context = {'users':users}
    return render(request,'yourpage.html',context)
```

In yourpage.html

```html
{% for users in users %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{users.username}}</td>
    <td>{{users.email}}</td>
    <td>
        {%for group in users.groups.all %}
        {{ group.name }}
        {%endfor%}
    </td>
```

this will display all users with their group