# django user group from request user

Tags: python, django, admin

I have assigned a user to a group say `developer` and in my admin I want a query like:

```
user_group = request.user.groups
```

Its giving me `auth.Group.None` though I have assigned a user in that group.

Why I am getting None while I have already assigned a user to the group

Comment: Did you save the User after you assigned the group to it ?

Answer (score 3):

As MattH pointed out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245908/5936450 you could use the following (slightly altered for your example):

```
user_group = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have first to query all groups of a specific user using this

```
request.user.groups.all()
```

it will return a list of groups for that user

then for a getting a specific one, suppose  it is the first element in the list

```
group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
```